# I was trying to make a switch from Unity to KDE, and now my laptop hangs on boot

Tags: unity, kde

I recently asked how I could remove Unity after installing KDE (used kubuntu-desktop), and was told to run a long apt-get command that boiled down to "purge these Unity packages and make sure kubuntu-desktop is installed with a reinstall".

I ran it and restarted, and now my laptop hangs up when I boot. I end up on a black screen, without even the backlight.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

When you are in the grub menu when you turn the computer on, type 'e' and you will enter the boot loader commands screen, and you will see an area which says 'quiet splash'. I want you to type nomodeset after this so it will look like this 'quiet splash nomodeset'. This should work. If it does, follow the instructions here: 
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1613132

If it doesn't work, read these:

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Troubleshooting/BlankScreen

[My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

Comment: how do I save my changes so that they are actually used?

Comment: Did that work? You don't save your changes there. Just hit the button that it tells you to press to start it up after you've added that argument. If it works, then you save the changes in your grub conf file. The instructions for doing so are in one of the links provided.

Comment: well now, I have an older splash. Monospace text reads Kubuntu 13.10 while dots flash orange underneath. It's been doing this for about 15 minutes. It also said I'm in low graphics mode. edit: the text and dots just disapeared, but the orange dots are still animating